# send data as string in jquery on handler

Tags: jquery

i'm wondering if i can send a data for a function as string (instead of object) using the .on handler

i've treid the following :

```
$(".news").on("click","news",popUp);
$(".news").on("click",null,"news",popUp);
```

to call this function with "news" as data:

```
function popUp (file = "none", opts= {})
{
    alert(file);
}
```

but this is not working ..

i don't want to send data as object because I'm using this function elsewhere and i don't want to change the function structure.

and can i send string data for **file** and object data for **opts** ??

Comment: Why not `.on("click", function() { popUp("news", { "foo": "bar" }); )` ?

Comment: yes this will work. but i was trying to understand the data type in on handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second call to `.on()` is correct (if the data is a string, you need to pass a `null` selector, otherwise the data will be assumed to be the selector for a delegated event).

But the data is in `event.data` in the handler, not a function argument.

```js
$(".news").on("click", null, "news", popUp);

function popUp(event) {
  alert(event.data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="news">Click</button>
```

If you want to send multiple parameters, use an object.

```js
$(".news").on("click", {
  file: "news",
  options: {
    something: "blah blah"
  }
}, popUp);

function popUp(event) {
  if (event.data) {
    let {
      file: file,
      options: opt
    } = event.data;
    alert(file + " " + opt.something);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="news">Click</button>
```